# Gensim Word2Vec changing the input sentence order?

Tags: gensim, word2vec

In the gensim's documentation `window` size is defined as,

> *window* is the maximum distance between the current and predicted word within a sentence.

which should mean when looking at context it doesn't go beyond the sentence boundary. right?

What i did was i created a document with several thousand tweets and selected a word (`q1`) and then selected most similar words to `q1` (using `model.most_similar('q1')`). But then, if I randomly shuffle the tweets in the input document and then did the same experiment (without changing word2vec parameters) I got a different set most_similar words to `q1`.

Can't really understand why that happens if only it's gonna look at is sentence level information? can anyone explain this?

**EDIT: added model parameters and a graph**

used model parameters:

```
model1 = word2vec.Word2Vec(sents1 , size=100, window=5, min_count=5, iter=n_iter, sg=0)
```

**Graph**: 
To draw the graph what i did was I ran word2vec with above parameters for the original document (D) and the shuffled document (D') and took the top 10 or 20 (two bars) `most_similar('q')` words to a specific query word `q`, and calculated the jaccard similarity score between the two sets of words when iter=1,10,100.

It seems as the no of iterations increase, lesser and lesser similar words between the two sets of words got from running word2vec on D and D'.

can't really understand why this is happening or what's going on?

[image]

Comment: Can you mention your training parameters? Vectors learned can differ based on negative sampling, threading, initialization etc. In order for vectors to stabilize, make sure to train your model for large number of iterations

Comment: please see the edit..

Comment: that's weird indeed, would it be possible for you to share your input data?

Comment: input data file contains about 1800 tweets that i have crawled from some twitter user. how could u send me ur email address or something?