# Does word2vec realization from gensim go beyond sentence level when examining context?

Tags: word2vec, gensim, word-embedding

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36790867) which provides evidence that sentence order probably matters (but effect can be also a result of different random initialization).

I want to process [Reddit comment dumps](https://files.pushshift.io/reddit/comments/) for my project, but the strings extracted from json would be unsorted and belong to very different subreddits and topics, so I don't want to mess up contexts:

```
{"gilded":0,"author_flair_text":"Male","author_flair_css_class":"male","retrieved_on":1425124228,"ups":3,"subreddit_id":"t5_2s30g","edited":false,"controversiality":0,"parent_id":"t1_cnapn0k","subreddit":"AskMen","body":"I can't agree with passing the blame, but I'm glad to hear it's at least helping you with the anxiety. I went the other direction and started taking responsibility for everything. I had to realize that people make mistakes including myself and it's gonna be alright. I don't have to be shackled to my mistakes and I don't have to be afraid of making them. ","created_utc":"1420070668","downs":0,"score":3,"author":"TheDukeofEtown","archived":false,"distinguished":null,"id":"cnasd6x","score_hidden":false,"name":"t1_cnasd6x","link_id":"t3_2qyhmp"}
```

So does the neighbor sentences matter for gensim word2vec and should I recover whole comment tree structure, or I can simply extract "bag of sentences" and train the model on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corpus expected by gensim Word2Vec is an *iterable* of *lists-of-tokens*. (For example, a list of lists-of-tokens would work, but for larger corpuses you'd usually want to provide a restartable iterable that streams text examples from persistent storage, to avoid holding the whole corpus in memory.)

The word-vector training only considrs context *within individual text examples*. That is, within one list-of-tokens. So if two consecutive examples are...

```
['I', 'do', 'not', 'like', 'green', 'eggs', 'and', 'ham']
['Everybody', 'needs', 'a', 'thneed']
```

...there's no influence, in these examples between 'ham' and 'Everybody'. (The contexts are only within each example.)

Still, there could be subtle effects on quality if the ordering of examples clumps together all words or topics of a certain type. For example, you'd not want all examples of word X to happen in the beginning of the corpus, and all examples of word Y to happen late – that prevents the sort of interleaved variety-of-examples that achieves the best results.

So if your corpus comes in any kind of sorted order, clumped by topic or author or size or language, it is often beneficial to perform an initial shuffle to remove such clumping. (Re-shuffling any more, such as between training passes, usually has negligible additional benefit.)

Comment: Thank you very much and please excuse me for the late response! I guess Reddit dumps have comments quite mixed up, so you saved me from a huge pile of work of reconstructing their structure.